# Wechat : Sandbox API config Failed

Tags: php, wechat

Hi please support to troubleshoot the below error in Wechat Sandbox API Config:

I am integrating Wechat API in PHP application. I have created a test account in Wechat Sandbox API. But when configuring the API with URL and token its shows "Unable to configure".

When checking the ajax response it throws : {"errcode":-106,"errmsg":"token check fail"}

Thank you.

Comment: @op: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes I have fixed

Comment: I managed to fix mine too. The problem was my server wasnt accessible from mainland china

Answer (score 0):

I got the "Unable to configure" message when testing the Getting Started wiki sample too. Trying to reach wx_sample.php returned a 500 Internal Server Error. 
It was fixed after changing the owners for my directory and file, after that the token could be set in the sandbox - 'API Config'.

Comment: What do you mean by changing the owner for your directory and file? You mean on your webserver? Why would that matter to Wechat?